# Не загружаются изображения в WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

В общем, имеется некое изображение (file), однако Image не хочет его отображать. Вот код, с помощью которого я пытаюсь вывести изображение:

```
    BitmapImage bitmp = new BitmapImage();
    bitmp.BeginInit();
    bitmp.UriSource = new Uri(file, UriKind.Relative);
    bitmp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmp.EndInit();

    return bitmp;
```

Возаращается ImageSource. Что тут может быть не так? Возвращаемое изображение ставится в Image.Source. Пробовал ставить относительный и абсолютный Uri, однако это не изменило ситуации.

Comment: А что пишется интересного в окошке Output?

Comment: И да, что у вас в `file`?

Comment: В file находится относительный путь к картинке (в моем случае `imgres\somefile.png`, а в output - `System.Windows.Data Error: 1 : Cannot create default converter to perform 'one-way' conversions between types 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task 1[System.Windows.Media.ImageSource]' and 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'. Consider using Converter property of Binding. BindingExpression:Path=PlayerIcon; DataItem='<>f__AnonymousType6 8' (HashCode=144639410); target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо VladD за намек, проблема была в том, что я забыл добавить .Result к функции, получилось `GetImage("path").Result`, т.к. функция - асинхронная

Comment: Если у вас функция асинхронная, лучше использовать не блокирующий Result, а await. Но подождите, _какая_ функция у вас асинхронная?

Comment: Та, которая и возвращает изображение

Comment: Но в коде, который вы привели, всё синхронно. Может быть, эта функция синхронная вся?